# Group repeated array and display rest in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, duplicates

I have a JSON array and 'age value' is repeated in the array, but each repeated 'age' has a different name' and 'occupation' in each index. now I want to display only one 'age' and all the values of other indexes. below is the example

```
0:{age: 22, name: Jack McDonald, occupation: Teacher }
0:{age: 22, name: Bridget Williams, occupation: Social Worker}
0:{age: 22, name: Nathan Thomas, occupation: Agriculture}
0:{age: 23, name: Olivia Beck, occupation: pilot}
0:{age: 24, name: Derek wilson, occupation: Translater}
```

I am displaying this information as it is in the table format. But I want to display it as

```
AGE      Name           Occupation
22   Jack McDonald       Teacher 
     Bridget Williams   Social Worker
     Nathan Thomas      Agriculture
23   Olivia Beck         pilot
24   Derek Wilson      Translator
```

Please suggest me on how is this possible. thank you

Answer (score 0):

If the order is guaranteed, simply iterate over the array and display the age if it's different from the previous:

```
const people = [
  { age: 22, name: "Jack McDonald", occupation: "Teacher" },
  { age: 22, name: "Bridget Williams", occupation: "Social Worker" },
  { age: 22, name: "Nathan Thomas", occupation: "Agriculture" },
  { age: 23, name: "Olivia Beck", occupation: "pilot" },
  { age: 24, name: "Derek wilson", occupation: "Translater" }
];

export default () => {
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Age</td>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>Job</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {people.map((person, index) => {
          let ageDisplay = person.age;
          if (people[index - 1] && people[index - 1].age === ageDisplay) {
            ageDisplay = '';
          }

          return (
            <tr>
              <td>{ageDisplay}</td>
              <td>{person.name}</td>
              <td>{person.occupation}</td>
            </tr>
          )
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-euler-3ukh7

Comment: thanks for your response, it would be easy to display if I have a custom table but I am using MUIDatatable, need to send array to the table with removed repeated columns but one

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a new array with a new data structure. The new array's data structure will contain item's with unique age and and array for the people:

```
{
    age: cur.age,
    people: [
         {
             name: '',
             occupation: ''
         }
    ]
}
```

Sample Code:

```js
(() => {
  // Sample Data:
  let data = [{
      age: 22,
      name: "Jack McDonald",
      occupation: "Teacher"
    },

    {
      age: 22,
      name: "Bridget Williams",
      occupation: "Social Worker"
    },

    {
      age: 22,
      name: "Nathan Thomas",
      occupation: "Agriculture"
    },
    {
      age: 23,
      name: "Olivia Beck",
      occupation: "pilot"
    },
    {
      age: 24,
      name: "Derek wilson",
      occupation: "Translater"
    }

  ];

  // update the accumulated array with the current person
  function accumulate(acc, cur) {
    // search the accumulator array for a matching current item's age
    let item = acc.find(data => {
      return data.age === cur.age;
    });

    // if not found, create a new item
    if (item == null) {
      item = {
        age: cur.age,
        people: []
      }
      acc.push(item);
    }

    // add the current item's name and occupation to the item's poeple array
    item.people.push({
      name: cur.name,
      occupation: cur.occupation
    })

    // return the new accumulator
    return acc;

  }

  let newArray = data.reduce((acc, cur, index) => {;
    // create a new accumulator array at the first pass through
    // and add the first item from the data array
    let _acc = (index === 1) ? accumulate([], acc) : acc;

    // add the current item to the accumulate array
    _acc = accumulate(_acc, cur);
    return _acc;

  });


})()
```

The new array will be:

```
[
{
    "age": 22,
    "people": [
        {
            "name": "Jack McDonald",
            "occupation": "Teacher"
        },
        {
            "name": "Bridget Williams",
            "occupation": "Social Worker"
        },
        {
            "name": "Nathan Thomas",
            "occupation": "Agriculture"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "age": 23,
    "people": [
        {
            "name": "Olivia Beck",
            "occupation": "pilot"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "age": 24,
    "people": [
        {
            "name": "Derek wilson",
            "occupation": "Translater"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and sorry for the late response. I am getting an error that says "Cannot read property 'accumulate' "

Comment: @DNP did you rename the sample code's function's name 'accumulate' to something else? If so you will need to update the array's reducer from the sample.

Comment: thanks for your response, it worked, I just had to adjust my table. thank you